# Attempting to use Vundle, but vundle#begin() is an unknown function. Runtimepath is correct

Tags: vim, vundle

I am trying to use Vundle to manage gVim plugins, but I can't get past an error when starting up Vundle in my gvimrc file. "unknown function: `vundle#begin()`"

This is usually some runtimepath problem, but I can clearly see that the directory of Vundle.vim is in my runtimepath.

My gvimrc file is in `C:\Users\Username`, and my vim installation is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim`. My Vundle installation is in `C:\Users\Username\.vim\bundle\Vundle.vim...` and my run time path variable clearly includes this file path.

Here is the relevant text of my gvimrc:

```
set nocompatible        
syntax on
filetype off            

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize 
set rtp+=C:\Users\username\\.vim\bundle\Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'path etc.'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

I can successfully run PluginInstall and install some plugins, but I can't get vim to use Vundle. What more can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's caused by Windows path, try this:

```
let $vundle='C:/Users/username/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim'
set rtp+=$vundle
```